# Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint - calve foranea de una tabla

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysqldb, foranea

estoy practicando con mysql workbench y al momento de agregar la clave foranea de "ciudad" me da un error.
Estoy usando:

- mysql 5.7
- mysql workbench 8.0.29
- Engine InnoDB por defecto

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS InfinitySports;
CREATE DATABASE InfinitySports CHARSET utf8mb4;
USE InfinitySports;

CREATE TABLE `Paises` (
`Nombre` varchar(15),
`Ciudad` varchar(20),
PRIMARY KEY (`Nombre`, `Ciudad`)
);

CREATE TABLE `Equipo` (
`Nombre` varchar(20) PRIMARY KEY,
`Entrenador` varchar(40),
`Pais` varchar(15),
`Ciudad` varchar(20)
);

ALTER TABLE `Equipo` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`Pais`) REFERENCES `Paises` (`Nombre`);

ALTER TABLE `Equipo` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`Ciudad`) REFERENCES `Paises` (`Ciudad`);#Esta linea da error: "Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint"
```

PD: Gracias.

Comment: [fijate](https://www.percona.com/blog/2017/04/06/dealing-mysql-error-code-1215-cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint/), te dejo algunos motivos que generan ese error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agrega antes de los alter un indice al atributo Ciudad de la tabla Paises y de va a dejar.

```
ALTER TABLE `Paises` ADD INDEX `ciudad` (`Ciudad`);
```

Comment: `InnoDB` no debería crear los indices automaticamente?

Comment: Los crea automaticamente el tema es que al usar una clave combinada necesita que le especifiques